# Verify Joi validation was added to hapi route

Tags: node.js, validation, testing, hapi.js, joi

I am reusing a Joi schema in multiple places in my code and I would like to find a clean way to test that my endpoints are assigned the validation schema. This would be helpful since I could verify the schema behaved the way I expect without having to repeat the same series of tests everywhere the schema is used.

If I have a hapi server route:

```
server.route({
  method: POST,
  path: 'myUrl',
  config: {
    validate: {
      payload: validation.myJoiValidation,
    }
  }
})
```

how would I test that the validation.myJoiValidation object has been assigned to the config.validate.payload element?

I dug down into the hapi request object and found that what I am looking for is located in the `request.route.settings.validate.payload._inner.children` object, but I really don't want to have to rely on that for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a server running in the context of your test, you can get the validation schema being used with:

```
const schema = server.match('post', 'myUrl').settings.validate.payload;
```

Schemas can't be directly compared (as with `Hoek.deepEqual`), but they can be compared by using `joi.describe`, so:

```
expect(joi.describe(schema)).to.equal(joi.describe(validation.myValidation));
```

Or, if you are using `mocha`/`chai` I think this would be:

```
expect(joi.describe(schema)).to.deep.equal(joi.describe(validation.myValidation));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your unit tests make a request with [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or similar package with a payload that doesn't pass the validation.  Ensure the response code is a 400.

[Example test](https://github.com/gangstead/keepalive-service/blob/e4012f9f16350df6bdd52217101ed0068a3d731f/test/routes/users-test.js#L88) from a project of mine.  It tests a regex Join validation on [this route](https://github.com/gangstead/keepalive-service/blob/e4012f9f16350df6bdd52217101ed0068a3d731f/routes/users.js#L30).  This uses a small promise wrapper around request called [yarp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarp).

Comment: I'm already doing something like this, but looking for an alternative. When the same validation is used on multiple endpoints then there is repetition in the unit tests for the validation. I would like to commonize those tests and have only one set of tests for a validation schema and then verify simply that each endpoint has that validation schema assigned to it.

Comment: If it's the schema you don't trust then you have comprehensive unit tests for the schema (outside of any route), then you just have one simple on the route to verify that there is a schema on it.  On our team we operated under the principal that our unit tests weren't there to duplicate hapi's and joi's.  Unless we were trying to do something unusual on a particular route we didn't exhaustively test every schema on every route.

Comment: What do you mean by verifying that there is a schema on a route? You mean any schema, but not a particular schema? The reason I want to verify the exact schema applied is because this app has strict requirements for what the incoming data should look like. So I would like to verify both that a schema contains the desired Joi validation as you suggest, but also verify that exact schema was assigned where expected.

Comment: Like I said, I'm not repeating unit tests.  If I put a schema on there I'll write one unit test to verify it doesn't take a malformed payload.  If it's a schema I use a lot I'll save the schema in it's own file and write a bunch of tests for that unit to cover it exhaustively.  There isn't a schema ID or anything you can verify is on a route. If you absolutely must check the exact schema on every route just write a function that takes a route and performs multiple unit tests on it.